# Webpack - Load a function from a non-moduled file?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Say I have a file :

```
//nonModuled.js
//A non moduled file  , let's say I can't "module" it

console.log('0');
function go(a)
    {
        console.log('go:' + a);
    }
```

And I have another file which I want to get the `go` function  :

```
//1.js
require('./nonModuled.js');
```

When I run the html file  , I do see the `console.log` , But I get an error for the `go` function :

[image]

I do understand why it's happening. Also - I know that I can do this patch :

```
//nonModuled.js
//A non moduled file  , let's say I can't touch it

console.log('hello');
window.go = function go(a)
    {
        console.log('go:' + a);
    }
```

And then in the `1.js` file  , access `window.go` but that seems clumsy.

And so I ask :

**Question:**

How can I get the `go` function properly ?

It would be nice if I could do  something like :

```
var a= require('./nonModuled.js');
a.go()
```

Any help ?

Comment: Why not export `go` from `nonModule.js`?

Comment: @SimpleJ _A non moduled file  , let's say I can't touch it_ , it's a library with many complicated  IIFEs and I don't want to get into that. However I did find a solution using `exports_loader` I will post an answer which may help others. Thanks

Comment: I see. I found the same thing, but your example made me think you had access to modify `nonModule.js`, so I thought you might just not know how dependencies in webpack worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're unable to make `nonModule.js` properly export `go`, you could use the [exports loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/exports-loader) to import it:

```
const go = require('exports-loader?go!./nonModule.js');
```

Comment: :-) Look in my comments. Thanks this is the right approach though .