# Webpack: Using non-module javascript file with dependency on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

Despite dozens of questions regarding using jquery with webpack, I can't figure out how to include JS file that depends on jquery and achieve the same effect as a script tag. Every approach mentioned on github or Stack Overflow are not explained in details and none have worked for me. In addition, I don't have experience with webpack.

I found those questions that sound close enough to mine but they do not answer this question specifically: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack) & [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825936/jquery-is-not-defined-when-using-webpack-to-load-bootstrap?noredirect=1&lq=1) & [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907837/webpack-load-a-function-from-a-non-moduled-file). Those questions do not provide steps for achieving this result.

**Overview**:
I'm using this [template](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/templates/KnockoutSpa). I have replaced the nav-html file with code that requires a (non-module) JS file. The code in the file does not export anything and it should run globally.

See this [commit](https://gitlab.com/AbuSalaa7/temp/commit/16fee1329c172bd6ccdaab25f00ad1fd453e6123) for the base template before any changes.

Approach 1:
Included the js file in the vendor array in the webpack.config.vendor.js, check this [commit](https://gitlab.com/AbuSalaa7/temp/commit/4c0102c435644e9a9dfb9eb452bebac3e0aa5083#f4b7d58b4573aecbc82317541c98843a77801aa6)

Result 1: I can see the code in the vendor.js but when I put a breakpoint on chrome dev tools the code is not hit

Approach 2:
Added require for the js file inside the boot.ts. Note that it is not a module. Check this [commit](https://gitlab.com/AbuSalaa7/temp/commit/36aa983cb66e90890ebdb0df71e2963e08a8a0df#d8c9b58384cc5b0554a7e4aa7a87c84c0fb9fad1).

Result 2: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Approach 3:
Used Script loader. Check this [commit](https://gitlab.com/AbuSalaa7/temp/commit/1b79e1a7d461371ea2f72ed83b1ad30e4c262c95).

Result 3: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: So why don't you want to include jQuery using a script tag?

Comment: @ChrisG jquery is already included in the vendor.js why include it again? The way I see it, it's either I use webpack to bundle together libraries and dependencies or use script tags all the way.

Comment: When I added jQuery to my react app, I had to add `/* global $ */` after my import lines.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I haven't looked at you code but hopefully this helps.

You can expose anything in a module to the global scope just by creating a global var within one of you modules.

```
import * as $ from 'JQuery';
window.$ = $;
```

This will allow your non-module code to reference the Jquery that was loaded as a module.